# creating multiple user with parameterised in pupet module

Tags: puppet

I am new to puppet world . I have to create a module to create a multiple users ,parameterized .

I have created a module as below . Not sure if that proper .

```
class users () {
    group { "sysadmin":
        ensure => present,
    }

    define users::add ($username, $groupname= "" ,$shell= "",$ensure, $login= false) {
        user { "$username":
            ensure => "$ensure" ,
            groups => "$groupname"  ,
            shell =>  "$shell" ,
            require => Group["sysadmin"]  ,
        }
    }
}
```

I have to create multiple user with above code . how and where to create that . Can I call in the same file ?(init.pp)

I tried by appending below line in the same file

```
class users::add {
    users::add { "user1": username => "myuser1"  , groupname => "sysadmin" , shell => "/bin/bash"  , ensure => present  , login => true }
    users::add { "user2": username => "myuser2"  , groupname => "sysadmin" , shell => "/bin/bash"  , ensure => present  , login => true }
}
```

it is not working .

Any help is highly appreciable . Thanks in advance .

Comment: You apparently fail to include the class `users::add`. This is probably the root of your issue. Cosmetics: 1. Don't call the define `users::add`. Call it `users::user`. 2. Don't call the class the same as the define. 3. Don't nest the define in `class users`. Call it `users::user` and declare it in `modules/users/manifests/user.pp`.

Answer (score 0):

for multiple actions you should better use `define` instead of `class` like this:

```
define users::account::add(
 $userid,
 $fullname,
 $groups,
 $shell,
 $password = '',
 $home_path = hiera('global::home_path')
) {
 group { $name:
  gid       => $userid,
  ensure    => 'present',
 } ->
 user { $name:
  uid       => $userid,
  gid       => $userid,
  comment   => $fullname,
  home      => "${home_path}/${name}",
  shell     => $shell,
  password  => $password,
  ensure    => 'present',
  groups    => $groups,
 }
}
```

this define may be used directly one or several times:

```
users::account::add { 'root':
 userid     => 0,
 groups     => [ ],
 fullname   => 'kroot',
 shell      => "${global::bash}",
 password   => '',
 home_path  => '',
}
users::account::add { 'raven':
 userid     => 1001,
 groups     => [ "${global::def_group}" ],
 fullname   => 'super admin',
 shell      => "${global::bash}",
 password   => '*',
}
users::account::add { 'admin':
 userid     => 1002,
 groups     => [ "${global::def_group}" ],
 fullname   => 'other admin',
 shell      => "${global::bash}",
 password   => '*',
}
```

much pretty variant is using this define with hiera:

```
class users::accounts {
 create_resources('add', hiera('users'))
}
```

while hieradata should contain users data:

```
{
 "users": {
  "root": {
   "userid": "0",
   "groups": [ ],
   "fillname": "kroot",
   "shell": "/bin/sh",
   "password": "",
   "home_path": ""
  },
  "raven": {
   "userid": "1001",
   "groups": [ "root", "wheel" ],
   "fillname": "super admin",
   "shell": "/usr/local/bin/bash",
   "password": ""
  },
  "admin": {
   "userid": "1002",
   "groups": [ "root", "wheel" ],
   "fillname": "other admin",
   "shell": "/usr/local/bin/bash",
   "password": ""
  }
 }
}
```